# Automatic merge back to develop in BitBucket

Tags: merge, bitbucket, git-flow

I previously worked on a project using the Gitflow Workflow and BitBucket. When a PR was merged into a release branch then it was automatically merged back into develop.
This does not happen in BitBucket on the project I am working on now and I cannot find any documentation on BitBucket regarding this. There is documentation on automatic branch merges but that seems to be to release branches only. Did BitBucket ever do this or was I somehow mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Git Flow, automating the back-merge of `release` into `develop` would be considered abnormal. You *can* do it constantly if you wish, but the only time `release` (or `main`) *needs* to be merged back into `develop` is after `release` is merged into `main`, or when a new change on the `release` branch is so important that `develop` can't wait for it it to reach `main` first.

My assumption is that no Git SCM tool would do any type of automatic branch merging by *default*. It does look like BitBucket has the ability to do this if you wish to [configure it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html). I suspect the previous project you worked on was using that exact feature.